# New to terminator on linux. Why aren't scrollback searches highlighted?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, highlighting, terminator

I'm using terminator on linux/ubuntu. When I do ctrl+shift f, I get a prompt to enter a search key to search my scrollback (terminal output). However, as I go through the search results one by one, none of the results are highlighted. I want them all highlighted like in iterm2 on Mac.

Is this a terminator feature? If so, how do I turn it on?

Answer (score 8):

There is a [bug report open on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/terminator/+bug/271487) for this feature, so it seems that it is not currently implemented.

Comment: It's very hurtful to see a simple bug (in terms of expectation)  take a decade to be fixed yet the fix isn't shipped yet.